# How to reinit bean object in previously autowired objects?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to reinit singleton bean instance for all previously autowired fields.

I tried to remove the bean from registy in app context, and re-register new object.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext configContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext)appContext;
SingletonBeanRegistry beanRegistry = configContext.getBeanFactory();
((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanRegistry).destroySingleton("fbdProg");
((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanRegistry).registerSingleton("fbdProg", program);
```

It works only once, the first time it is called.

The issue is how to reinit the bean to make new instance available in other classes, where it is autowired

Comment: "I need to reinit singleton bean instance" => Why? Better to simply change the already instantiated bean.

Comment: Wouldn't changing bean scope to prototype work for you?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose, sure, but how to share the ref of a new instance among all autowired "refs"?

Comment: Don't create a new instance. Feels like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a new instance of this bean everytime it is injected, you can use `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)` on your bean. E.g:

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MyComponent {
    // methods, fields, etc.
}
```

Spring then creates a new instance of `MyComponent` everytime it is injected into another component. So **Bean A** will have a different instance of `MyComponent` than **Bean B**, evaluating `beanA.myComponent != beanB.myComponent` to `true`

Comment: The idea is that one webController gets the command from Front-end to load something to new instance of class. In the same time, this instance should be used by other class(Like, new loaded instance, but loaded in other controller.)

Answer (score 0):

Every class with a @Bean annotation is a singleton by default in spring boot, but you can provide a @Scope annotation if you want that the lifehook of a variable to be related to

- a session
- an http request
- the lifehook of a serveletContext

anyway you have to keep in mind that @Bean should be singleton, for example in the persistence pattern you have an entity and a repository. The respository should be a singletone because it essentialy gives only methods to store and retrieve entities, while an entity should not be a singletone because you need an entity for every object you have to store in a database. The same for services. You may also want to taake a look at this article: [spring boot scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)

Comment: Probably, I explain a bit incorrect. I need to recreat the singleton instance in runtime, and then share ref to new instance among all autowired "refs". Like, few objects use the one bean, that can be recreated during runtime.

Comment: a sigletone by definition is an immutable istance that "lives" for all the time the app is running, so my question is why to destroy a singletone? why modify? Give some more detailed info of what you are tryng to do in your application